# Взаимодействие между классами игры

Tags: android, шаблоны-проектирования, observer, шаблон-одиночка

В приложении для Android есть класс отвечающий за обратный отсчёт времени; класс с ходом игры; синглетный класс с настройками разных параметров игры. Класс с ходом игры должен прекратить игру, если игрок умрет. Класс с обратным отсчётом времени должен прекратить игру, если время выйдет. Каким паттерном лучше воспользоваться для того, чтобы прекратить работу классов одновременно и не создавая сильные связи между ними (вышло время -> прекратить ход игры, умер игрок -> остановить обратный отсчёт времени)?

Есть разные режимы игры, режим игры на время привел для примера, по этому сильные связи между классами создавать нельзя.

---

На текущий момент у меня в к классе с настройками есть параметр, который хранит текущее состояние игры(запущен, завершен, на паузе и т.д.) у которого есть сеттер, который реализует паттерн обсервер и извещает всех подписчиков при измении состояния игры, а в классах времени и хода игры реализован слушатель данного события. Но код выглядит не элегантно. Может подскажете более мудрое решение?